# SAXParseException: SOAP request not working in production

Tags: curl, soap, soapui

I have a local environment and a production environment. In the local environment the SOAP request (from SoapUI) works nicely. But when I point it towards the production environment, it fails with the following error:

```
ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[...]; client=[...]; method=[POST]; 
servlet=[vmonline]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[2ms];
status=[failed: org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPFaultException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.]
```

Because the SOAP request works in the local environment, but fails in production, I'm pretty confident that request is not malformed. The only difference I know is that production has its endpoint behind https, while the local setup has its setup on http. Here is the request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vmo="...">
<soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1014" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>...</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">...</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <CheckStatusRequest>
     <Voucher>
        <ActivationCode>820551399636</ActivationCode>
     </Voucher>
  </CheckStatusRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I can't really figure out what might be the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I tried the same request through curl, and there it worked... What's the difference between curl and SoapUI doing a request

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The error mentioned is from the server log. So the message is sent, and when the application handles the message, it returns the error above. But as I said, when I do it through curl or through a python script, it works fine...

Comment: What does the server log say the request it received looks like?